# Expect script to run shell command

Tags: linux, tcl, expect

How to run a shell command in an expect script and check for some specific string?

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 20

send "ps -aef | grep P1"

expect "string"

Blah 
Blah

exit;
```

I tried with `spawn`, `exec` and `system` command in place of `send`, but it always timed out or ended in some error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern is you `spawn` the program, `expect` it to produce some output, `send` it some input, (repeat the last two as necessary), and `close; wait` to finish. If the program doesn't produce the expected output, you will wait until it finishes or you get a timeout.

Fortunately, you can wait for multiple things at once:

```
spawn ps -aef
expect {
    "P1" { ... got it ... }
    eof { ... not got it ... }
    timeout { ... ps hung? ... }
}
close
wait
```

Comment: Thanks. I had tried this with | (pipe) and grep. cant we use | (pipe) in system command?